# Can't use ImageMagick on Laravel 5 with Intervention Image

Tags: laravel-5, imagick, laravel-artisan

I followed these steps http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation for install  Intervention Image  library on Laravel 5. For now GD library is working which comes as a default library but i want to use imagemagick for this function  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_noisy . I ran `$php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"` command for pull configuration file into my application but i got **Publishing complete for tag[]!** message and nothing change. So what is my mistake or am i missing something?